# D3.js pseudo 3D bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d

I started looking into d3 and tried to create a histogram with 3D effect. Correctly calculated the position of all faces, but they are visible only cleanly and only in the browser's inspector. What's wrong with my code? (See method "updateChart")

[image]

Above, something interferes with the display. But I can't figure out what exactly

[image]

```
class BarChart extends React.Component {
   //skip code...

  updateChart() {
    this.updateScales();
    const { data, width, height, connectFauxDOM } = this.props;
    const { xAxisLength, yAxisLength } = this.getAxisLength();

    const faux = connectFauxDOM('div', 'chart');
    const svg = d3
      .select(faux)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin');

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(this.xScale);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(this.yScale);


    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x-axis')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        `translate(${this.margin},${height - this.margin})`,
      )
      .call(xAxis);

    svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y-axis')
      .attr(
        'transform', 
        `translate(${this.margin},${this.margin})`,
      )
      .call(yAxis);

    svg
      .selectAll('g.y-axis g.tick')
      .append('line')
      .classed('grid-line', true)
      .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr('x2', xAxisLength)
      .attr('y2', 0);
    const g = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'body').attr(
      'transform', 
      `translate(${this.margin}, 0 )`,
    );
    g.selectAll('svg.bar')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'bar');

    const angel = 45;
    const rectWidth = () =>
      Math.floor(xAxisLength / data.length) - this.padding;
    const rectHeight = (value) => yAxisLength - this.yScale(value);
    const rectX = (value) => this.xScale(value);
    const rectY = (value) => this.yScale(value) + this.margin;

    const bars = g
      .selectAll('svg.bar')
      .data(data)
      .attr('x', (d) => rectX(d.label))
      .attr('y', (d) => rectY(d.value));

    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'forward-bar')
      .attr('height', (d) => rectHeight(d.value))
      .attr('width', () => rectWidth());

    // side
    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'side-bar')
      .attr('width', rectWidth() / 2)
      .attr('height', (d) => rectHeight(d.value))
      .attr('transform', `translate (${rectWidth()}, 0) skewY(${-angel})`);

    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('rect')
      .attr('class', 'top-bar')
      .attr('width', rectWidth())
      .attr('height', rectWidth() / 2)
      .attr(
        'transform',
        `translate (${rectWidth() / 2},${-rectWidth() / 2}) skewX(${-angel})`,
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { chart, classes } = this.props;
    return <div className={classes.svg}>{chart}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think skewed `<rect>`s will not work, `<path>` is much more suitable for your task.

Here is a simple function add3DBar:

```js
const add3DBar = (parent, xPos, yPos, width, height, depth) => {
  const g = parent.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`);
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M 0,0 V ${-height} H ${width} V 0 H 0 Z`).style('fill', '#000080');
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M 0,${-height} L ${depth},${-height-depth} H ${depth + width} L ${width},${-height} Z`).style('fill', '#0000FF');
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M ${width},0 L ${width + depth},${-depth}, V ${-height-depth} L ${width} ${-height} Z`).style('fill', '#0000C0');
}
```

, where

**xPos** and **yPos** - coordinates of the bottom-left corner of the bar

**width**, **height**, **depth** - dimensions of the bar

See how it works in the fiddle:

```js
const add3DBar = (parent, xPos, yPos, width, height, depth) => {
  const g = parent.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`);
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M 0,0 V ${-height} H ${width} V 0 H 0 Z`).style('fill', '#000080');
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M 0,${-height} L ${depth},${-height-depth} H ${depth + width} L ${width},${-height} Z`).style('fill', '#0000FF');
  g.append('path').attr('d', `M ${width},0 L ${width + depth},${-depth}, V ${-height-depth} L ${width} ${-height} Z`).style('fill', '#0000C0');
}

const svg = d3.select('svg');

add3DBar(svg, 30, 150, 30, 100, 10);
add3DBar(svg, 70, 150, 30, 70, 10);
add3DBar(svg, 110, 150, 30, 120, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this way to build 3D. But what about "growing up" animation? Its hard?

Comment: I think it's doable. Can you please post a new question, I will try to answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457363/d3-js-growing-up-path-animation-for-3d-bar-chart. Done)