# D3.js "growing up" path animation for 3d bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, 3d

I am trying to add classic animation to pseudo-3D bar chart. It's very simple to do it right with rect. But what about path ?

[image]

I have three basic paths for the 3d effect:
How to make a harmonious growing animation?

```
  createColumns(bars, data) {
    //...skip code

    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('path')
      .attr(
        'd',
        (d) => `M 0,0 V ${rectHeight(d.value)} H ${rectWidth()} V 0 H 0 Z`,
      )
      .attr('class', 'forward-bar')
      .classed('bar', true);

    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('path')
      .attr(
        'd',
        () =>
          `M 0,0 L ${rectWidth()},0 L ${
            rectWidth() + depth
          }, ${-depth} H ${depth} Z`,
      )
      .attr('class', 'top-bar')
      .classed('bar', true);

    bars
      .data(data)
      .append('path')
      .attr(
        'd',
        (d) =>
          `M ${rectWidth()},0 L ${rectWidth() + depth},${-depth}, V ${
            rectHeight(d.value) - depth
          } L ${rectWidth()} ${rectHeight(d.value)} Z`,
      )
      .attr('class', 'side-bar')
      .classed('bar', true);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented with D3 Transition (set duration in milliseconds):

```js
const add3DBar = (parent, xPos, yPos, width, height, depth, duration) => {
  const g = parent.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(${xPos}, ${yPos})`);
  
  g.append('path')
   .attr('d', `M 0,0 V ${0} H ${width} V 0 H 0 Z`)
   .style('fill', '#000081')
   .transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr('d', `M 0,0 V ${-height} H ${width} V 0 H 0 Z`);
  
  g.append('path')
   .attr('d', `M 0,${0} L ${depth},${-depth} H ${depth + width} L ${width},0 Z`)
   .style('fill', '#0000FF')
   .transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr('d', `M 0,${-height} L ${depth},${-height-depth} H ${depth + width} L ${width},${-height} Z`);

  g.append('path')
   .attr('d', `M ${width},0 L ${width + depth},${-depth}, V ${-depth} L ${width},0 Z`)
   .style('fill', '#0000C0')
   .transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr('d', `M ${width},0 L ${width + depth},${-depth}, V ${-height-depth} L ${width},${-height} Z`);
}

const svg = d3.select('svg');

add3DBar(svg, 30, 150, 30, 100, 10, 500);
add3DBar(svg, 70, 150, 30, 70, 10, 1000);
add3DBar(svg, 110, 150, 30, 120, 10, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
</svg>
```